# Issues with XNA Gestures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

My XNA Gestures are not working. I am trying to create a weather app that will pull up a 7-day forecast when swiped up, and pull it away when swiped down. The left/right gestures are for switching pages. What am I doing wrong here? My app, when tested, gets confused and thinks every gesture is a left/right one or no gesture at all, sometimes. Why won't it detect up my up/down gestures, and why are the left/right ones so inaccurate?

Note: `GestureText.Text` is just for debugging.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.VerticalDrag | GestureType.HorizontalDrag;
}

private void gestures(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        switch (gesture.GestureType)
        {
            case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
                float a = gesture.Delta.X;
                int b = (int)a;
                if (b > 0)
                {
                    gestureText.Text = "Left";
                }
                if (b < 0)
                {
                    gestureText.Text = "Right";
                }
                break;
            case GestureType.VerticalDrag:
                float c = gesture.Delta.X;
                int d = (int)c;
                if (d > 0)
                {
                    gestureText.Text = "Up";
                }
                if (d < 0)
                {
                    gestureText.Text = "Down";
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `HorizontalDrag` and see if your game detects `VerticalDrag`?

Comment: Wrote my own gestures as suggested below. Working great & solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion will be to avoid using `Gestures` at all. There are too many problems with them and the best way to solve this issue is to write your own gestures using [TouchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.TouchCollection%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 0):

Your up/down gestures didn't get noticed since you're using `gesture.Delta.X` when you should have been using `gesture.Delta.Y`. The `VerticalDrag` gesture doesn't detect the horizontal changes.

Also the conditions for up/down detection should be the opposite way as `Vector2.Zero` is in the upper left corner